# How to check for certain chars in tokens

Tags: c

I have code in which I have tokenized a string, and printed the results. The code has a function in which I use some pointer arithmetic to change each token to repeat the work in "Pig Latin" The code also calls for me to print the word with WORD+WAY if the first letter of an individual token starts with a vowel. I think a switch(case) would work for this, but I am unsure of what string function to use to accomplish this

Below is the function for the base "Pig Latin" change.

```
printlatinwork (char *TOKEN)
{
    printf ("%s%c%s ", TOKEN + 1, TOKEN[0], "ay");
    return;
}
```

Which returns from input of "test"

```
esttay
```

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S
I need to check for the first character in each token, which are words. Then depending on if the first character is a vowel or not, either use printlatinwork() for non vowels, and a different function for vowels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't too difficult, just check the first character of `TOKEN` against a list of `vowels`. Something similar to:

```
void printlatinwork (char *TOKEN)
{
    char *vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";

    if (strchr (vowels, *TOKEN))
        printf ("%sway", TOKEN);
    else
        printf ("%s%c%s ", TOKEN + 1, TOKEN[0], "ay");
}
```

**Note:** requires `string.h`

If you need a version that does not rely on any additional header, something like this will work as well:

```
void printlatinwork (char *TOKEN)
{
    char *vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    char firstisvowel = 0;
    char *v = vowels;

    while (*v)
        if (*TOKEN == *v++)
            firstisvowel = 1;

    if (firstisvowel)
        printf ("%sway", TOKEN);
    else
        printf ("%s%c%s ", TOKEN + 1, TOKEN[0], "ay");
}
```

Comment: So strchr searches for the first appearance of any character from vowels in the current word I am using correct?